# mysql - backing up related innodb databases

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys, backup, restore

I have a question relating to the backing up of multiple MySQL innodb databases which have cross database relations with one another. A concern would be the relational integrity of the data during backup and restore of the databases.

The use case for this would be a situation where one "master" database is been used to hold top level data such as User information for multiple separate domains which cannot be consolidated into one database. Setting this up is not an issue as MySQL allows cross database relations with innodb foreign keys.

However, how would one properly back up the master and secondary databases (assuming they are on the same server) without breaking the foreign keys during back up.

I am looking for a way to some how capture a "snap shot" in time of those databases in that instant or if that is not possible to preserve the relations during backup time...

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understand the question correctly.

Suppose you have two databases (db1 and db2) where a foreign key constraint from one or more tables in db2 references something in db1.

If you want to make sure everything is point-in-time consistent when making a backup, you can let [***mysqldump***](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/mysqldump/info) do it for you. Whenever you run mysqldump, you issue the `--single-transaction` option like this:

```
mysqldump -u... -p... --single-transaction --databases db1 db2 > db1_db2.sql
```

An internal checkpoint is created so that db1 and db2 are consistent in terms of referential integrity and in point-in-time *EVEN IF DATA IS BEING ENTERED INTO db1 AND db2 DURING THE BACKUP*.

During the restore of a mysqldump, foreign keys are disabled to allow a clean, fast reload reload. You can trust the foreign keys being disabled during restore IF AND ONLY IF the mysqldump was made using the `--single-transaction` option.

Comment: Let me just say thank you for the excellent response. I think you understood my problem exactly. 

I have been looking at MySQL Enterprise and the following I had found:
Hot backups with MySQL Enterprise: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-enterprise-backup/3.5/en/meb-backup-overview.html
Backup command with MySQL ENterprise: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-enterprise-backup/3.6/en/intro.html

Comment: These look like quite interesting alternatives. The Backup command with MySQL enterprise looks the most user friendly approach than hot backup. However, from what I have understood with hotbackup is that it's payoff is its speed.

Comment: Other people have suggested that using FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK while performing a dump however this does seem to have a negative effect on long SQL statements that are still busy at the point of backup: 

see: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2012/03/23/how-flush-tables-with-read-lock-works-with-innodb-tables/

Comment: Anyone's thoughts on the above since I have no experience yet with them?